# My Sql AND Relation for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

How to write sql query for set of key value pairs using AND operation

Ex:

```
 id   proc_id     code     value
 1    1           height   ""
 2    1           weight   120
 3    1           chin     2
 4    1           lower    ""
 5    1           upper    10
```

I have values like this : {weight=120, lower=1, height=""}

How can i apply AND relation to match exact records 
output : return records - [2, 1] - # only weight and height matched .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three basic ways.

One is to join as many times as needed:

```
select n.node_id
from node n
join meta m1 on m1.node_id = n.node_id
            and m1.code = 'weight' and m1.value = '120'
join meta m2 on m2.node_id = n.node_id
            and m2.code = 'lower' and m2.value = '1'
join meta m3 on m3.node_id = n.node_id
            and m3.code = 'height' and m3.value = ''
```

The other is to group by and count:

```
select n.node_id
from node n
join meta m on m.node_id = n.node_id
where m.code = 'weight' and m.value = '120' or
      m.code = 'lower' and m.value = '1' or
      m.code = 'height' and m.value = ''
group by n.node_id
having count(*) >= 3
```

The last is to avoid using an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) where inappropriate and to normalize your data properly.

Comment: HI Denis, yes i was looking for this , my bad what is meta here. another join table ? . thanks

Comment: node is your data table (person? => id, name, etc). meta is your eav table (person_attribute? => id, proc_id, code, value).

Answer (score 2):

Since the individual values are in separate rows, you'd have to use an `OR` query:

```
select id, proc_id, code, value
FROM yourtable
WHERE (code='HEIGHT' and value = '120') OR
    (code='lower' AND value = '1') OR
    (code='height' AND value= '')
```

Comment: This is incorrect. He wants rows that match all of the criteria.

Comment: i tried this , but criteria should show records if both are true else no records. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely, but how about this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE weight = 120 AND lower = 1 AND height = ''
```

Comment: There's no 'weight' or 'lower' or 'height' fields for this query to work on. There's only "code" and "value"

Comment: Ah, it was so badly formatted at first wo I missed it! Yours is on the spot of course.